# localhost defaults to ipv6 address instead of ipv4 on fedora linux. Can't connect to mongodb from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, localhost, fedora

After a system update on **Fedora 36 Linux**, Localhost alias now uses the `ipv6` address by default which has broken a lot of my code.
For instance:

```
// Connecting to MongoDB using mongoose on express (nodejs)
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/farmStand')
.then(()=>{
    console.log('Connected to Mongo');
})
```

Does not work and throws this error:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
```

I've done some research and found multiple workarounds such as replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`, `localhost4` or even removing the following line,

```
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

from from `/etc/hosts`,

```
# Loopback entries; do not change.
# For historical reasons, localhost precedes localhost.localdomain:
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
# See hosts(5) for proper format and other examples:
# 192.168.1.10 foo.mydomain.org foo
# 192.168.1.13 bar.mydomain.org bar
```

However since this the former forces me to change a lot of code and the later is not recommended by the `hosts` file itself,
**How do i return `localhost` to its former state or bind `mongodb` to `ipv6`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your MongoDB with this settings:

```
net:
  bindIpAll: true
  ipv6: true
```

Then it should work